# Create flat array from 3rd level colimn values of a 3d array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I got a query result like this: -

```
[
    [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Japan']
    ],
    [
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Nepal']
    ],
];
```

How can I convert it to

```
Array
(
  [0] => Japan
  [1] => Nepal
)
```

The query used to get first array is: `SELECT id , name FROM country;`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($element as $array) {
    $element = $element[0]["name"];
}
```

Or,

```
function extractName($element) {
    return $element[0]["name"];
}

$newArray = array_map("extractName", $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dot notation inside of the `extract()` method from Cake1.2's `Set` class.

```
$newArray = Set::extract($oldArray, '{n}.0.name');
```

More [here](http://debuggable.com/posts/cake-12s-set-class-eats-arrays-for-breakfast:480f4dd6-d084-4fb7-bacc-49fdcbdd56cb).

Answer (score 0):

Flatten, then call `array_column()`: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/C7nbX)

```
var_export(
    array_column(
        array_merge(...$array),
        'name'
    )
);
```

---

If your data will only have single-elements in the second level, then...

`array_map()`: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/RB8Pn)

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => $v[0]['name'],
        $array
    )
);
```

Or array destructuring in a `foreach()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IdZUK))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as [['name' => $result[]]]);
var_export($result);
```